# Swift extention する意味

Tags: swift

Swiftでextention する意味はなんでしょう？ 書き足せば良くないですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

書き足せるもの（＝自分で書いたコード）については結果は同じなのでExtensionで書いても書き足してもどちらでも構いませんが、書き足せないコード、標準ライブラリやサードパーティ製のライブラリを拡張したいという場合にはExtensionとして書く以外にはありません。